# Prove $n^2 \leq 1.1 ^{n}$ by induction

Tags: inequality, induction, functional-inequalities

Prove that for all $n \geq 100$ you have  $n^2 \leq 1.1^n$

Base Case:

$n = 100$

$(100)^2 \leq 1.1^{100}$  (*True*)

Inductive Case:

Suppose $(k-1)^2 \leq 1.1^{k-1}$ for some $k \geq 101$

Prove $k^2 \leq 1.1^k$

I know $1.1^k = 1.1^{k-1} \cdot 1.1$

So I have,

$1.1^{k-1} \cdot 1.1 \geq 1.1(k-1)^2$

I know i need to eventually get $k^2$ on the RHS but I'm stuck

Comment: I made a few edits.  Most of them were simply putting equations into $\LaTeX$, but note a few key changes in the phrasing.  In particular, `Suppose ... for all k>100` should be corrected to `Suppose ... for some k>100`.  There is a big difference between the phrases *for all* and *for some*.

Comment: In my opinion, the hardest thing here is proving that $100^2 \le 1.1^n$.

Comment: @TonyK: Short of using log tables, I couldn't find a much easier way than to show, using the binomial theorem, that $(1+1/10)^{25} > 10$.  The first five terms suffice, just barely: $1+25/10+300/100+2300/1000+12650/10000 = 100650/10000 = 10.065$.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that for $n \geq 100$,

\begin{align}
(n+1)^2 & < \left(n+\frac{n}{40}\right)^2 \\
        & = n^2+\frac{n^2}{20}+\frac{n^2}{1600} \\
        & < n^2+\frac{n^2}{20}+\frac{n^2}{20} \\
        & = n^2+\frac{n^2}{10} = n^2 \left(1+\frac{1}{10}\right)
\end{align}

Use that in the induction step and all should be well.  Note that $n \geq 100$ is rather a loose condition for the induction step.

Comment: Not such a loose condition, I would say. It fails for $n=95$.

Comment: @TonyK: Not the overall proposition, just the induction step.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is maybe to note that it is equivalent to $2\log(n)\leq n\log(1.1)$ i.e. to $\frac{n}{\log(n)} \geq \frac2{\log(1.1)}$

The function $x\rightarrow \frac{x}{\log(x)}$ is increasing for x>100 (look at the derivative, it has the sign of $\log(x)-1$). So if you have the property for one $n$, you have it for all the next ones. Then, you only have to compute it for 100.